# Dual Monitor Issue

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, launcher, display

I have connected my laptop to an external display and setup the external display to be on the right of my laptop screen.  In the Display Settings, I have selected the option to have the launcher on both display.  Now when I launch any application from the launcher on the second display, the application launches on the first display.  Is this a bug, and how can I solve this problem